# How to prevent Ubuntu from putting my monitor to sleep AFTER locking?

Tags: ubuntu, display, sleep

Whenever I lock my Ubuntu system with CTRL+ALT+L, the monitor will be put to sleep in about 5-10 seconds. This is pretty frustrating, especially since I sometimes like to walk away for a half a minute to get a drink but like to keep privacy between me and my roommates. Now, when I come back, I have to wait for my monitor to wake back up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you researched this on your own ? Have you looked at the power management settings ?

Comment: Yes, and none of the solutions have worked.